# How to run mocha using sudo on Travis

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci, sudo

I'm trying to create raw sockets in node, but I'm having trouble running mocha with sudo.

Calling `mocha` in either package.json or .travis.yml works (with the permissions error for the socket)

Trying to call `sudo mocha` in either file gets me a file not found error.

```
$ sudo mocha

sudo: mocha: command not found

The command "sudo mocha" exited with 1.
```

I do have `sudo: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the mocha call to your ***package.json*** scripts like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": // do something
  "test": "mocha"
}
```

Then set it up on ***travis.yml*** with:

`script: "sudo $(which npm) test"`

More help here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1305

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, as that is calling npm to run a script, vs running mocha. I'm still fiddling with it though.

Comment: Can't you set a npm script to run mocha on your package.json? Like `"scripts": { "test" : "mocha /spec/**/*.js" }` then call it with npm test

Comment: I was over-thinking it. Thank you so much.